# Rails 4 ActionMailer not sending emails in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer, devise-confirmable

First, let me specify that **I am aware that ActionMailer does *NOT* send emails by default in development mode**.

Also, I took a look at similar questions, and none of them was relevant to my situation.

So, here we go:

1. I am following [this *Site Point* tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/) by Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski, from March 26, 2015 in order to install and setup Devise on my Rails 4 app.
2. Because we activated Devise's `confirmable` module, I need to send emails in development to allow users who signup to activate their account and login.
3. Whenever I create a new user (through `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`), I do get the following alert:

> A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email
>   address. Please follow the link to activate your account.

4. However, I never actually receive the email with the confirmation link.

——————————

**UPDATE**

In my development.log file, I can see that the email was "sent":

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 172.1ms

Sent mail to hello@mydomain.com (54.4ms)
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2015 12:15:15 -0700
From: contact@anotherdomain.com
Reply-To: contact@anotherdomain.com
To: hello@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <55dcbec3a1ef8_33b93fcffc4988f493685@XXXXXX.local.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome hello@mydomain.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=ZsL_iQVxfDQd7mB1RkGf">Confirm my account</a></p>

  [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 560ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

And, when I copy and paste the link from the log into my browser, then I get the following alert:

> Signed in successfully.

So, it seems the only thing that is not working is the actual sending / receiving of the email.

——————————

As recommended in the tutorial, I followed Rails documentation regarding [ActionMailer configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) and here is what I have in my `config/environments/development.rb file`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  # Defaults to:
  # config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  #   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  #   arguments: '-i -t'
  # }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'hello@mydomain.com'}
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

Obviously, I am missing something, but I cannot figure out what (I am very, very junior with Rails).

Any idea?

Comment: what mail server are you using?

Comment: Very good question. How / where can I get you this information? (Maybe that's my problem: I don't think I have setup a mail server).

Comment: Try [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/). It makes dealing with emails in development much less of a PITA.

Comment: What is your `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` specified?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there any way to make emails work in development mode without using a third-party solution (i.e. only using Rails default configuration options)?

Comment: I have: `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mail is not sent in development by default. To enable this you have to set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` in `development.rb` file which I see you already have.

You may also have to enable `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to raise delivery errors. That way, you will be able to see if there are any errors in the email delivery process.

Also, double check your `default from` if that has a valid email.

Also try switching the delivery method to `sendmail`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the question, I already have `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail` and `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` defined. Is there something else that could cause the issue? Is there any log I can pull to understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` as well?
Then it should show some error if there is any while delivering

Comment: Yes, I do. You can see all my configuration for `config/environments/development.rb file` in the question. And I have no error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mail server for Action Mailer to send emails.
such as
[MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/)
which has a free account and a gem which makes set up easy.
[mailgun_rails](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/mailgun_rails)